# Revert the Document.ready

Tags: jquery, document

```
 if (month == 2)
    {
        $(document).ready(function monthValidation() {
            //if ($("#Month option:selected").val() == 2) {
            //   //debugger;
            $("#Day option[value='31']").hide();
            $("#Day option[value='30']").hide();
            $("#Day option[value='29']").hide();
            if ($("#Year option:selected").text() == 2016) {
                $("#Day option[value='29']").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#Day option[value='29']").hide();
            }
        });
    }
```

this is a function it works on **page load** time but **after page load** i want to **revert** means i want to get my **previous values**? how can i do this?

Comment: reset with `$(window).load(fn);`